# What is the best way to discard of a WPF page in order to display a new version of that page with different data?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

In my program, navigation is structured along a path going Project->Board->Issue, then you are able to navigate back up to choose a different board. It displays the issues in a list which can be picked from. The trouble is that if you navigate to a different board, then choose a different issue from the ones displayed there, it still displays the first issue you selected.

I think the best solution is to dispose of the issue detail page when I navigate back, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Navigation from Board to Issues

```
private void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var loginWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    if (selectedBoard != null)
    {
        PageIssueSelect p = null;
        p = new PageIssueSelect(project, selectedBoard);
        loginWindow.Navigate(p);
    }
}
```

Navigation from Issue list back to Board:

```
private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    items.Clear();
    lbxIssues.ItemsSource = null;
    project = null;
    var mainWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    mainWindow.pageHolder.GoBack();
}
```

Navigation from Issue list to one issue:

```
private void LbxIssues_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox box = (ListBox)sender;
    var loginWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    Issue issue = project.Issues[box.SelectedIndex];
    pageIssueDetail p = null;
    p = new pageIssueDetail(issue, project.name);
    loginWindow.Navigate(p);
}
```

Navigation from one issue back to the issue list

```
{
    issue = null;
    var loginWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    loginWindow.pageHolder.GoBack();
}
```

As far as I can tell, there should be no reason for the same issue to always be displayed, as each time it navigates forward it is creating a new page with a new issue selected.

Some of the unnecessary code lines in these are from me trying to create some kind of solution to the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue laid in the data being fetched, not the pages. I was using

```
item = wholeList[index];
```

When I should have been using

```
item = filteredList[index];
```

Just answering in case this helps anyone else.